# Bootstrap row of col-sm-4 leaving a blank space at col-xs-6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my layout, but having a problem when going from 3 columns at col-sm-4 to the wanted 2 columns at col-xs-6, it's leaving a blank space after the third item. Any idea how this can be solver, so the layout goes from 3 columns to 2 in xs size?

```css
/** Style to illustrate the issue */

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green{
  background-color:green;
}

.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}

.sample {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 sample red">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 sample blue">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 sample green">3</div>
```

Comment: Please include a code snippet that is a minimal repro of your situation in the question.

Comment: this is expected behaviour. what would the desired outcome look like? Should the last col span full width in xs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your columns must always add up to 12. This is the case for your "sm" settings (3x4 = 12), but not for your "xs" settings.

In "xs" you will now have 3x "50%" columns (`col-xs-6`) so the 3rd one will go to the next line, leaving 50% blank space behind it.

If you want 2 columns in "xs" size, you will have to put 2 columns to `col-xs-6` and set a `col-hidden-xs` on one of the others to hide that one.

Comment: The layout is a gallery and they are dynamically loaded, so if I hide three of them in xs size, it might not be a good idea, any other suggestions?

Comment: Well.. if you have 3 columns, but want to display 2, something has got to give. So either go with col-xs-6, col-xs-6 and col-xs-12 (so 2x 50% and 1x 100%) or perhaps 3x col-xs-12 (100%). Either way.. you can't just show 3 columns as 2 colums.